# Postgresql Autovacuum. Is it necessary to to activate explicitly in Postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

For the postgres SQL >=9.0 the Autovacuum is by default `ON` and we can check it, but in `postgresql.conf` the status of Autovacuum is not `ON`

```
#autovacuum = on            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
```

Is it neccessary to turn `autovacuum on` explicitly?

Comment: If in doubt, `SHOW autovaccuum;` in `psql` will give you the current value the server is using.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is already on.

The convention of the initially-generated `postgres.conf` file is to document the default value with a commented-out setting.  So the setting is already on, because that is the default and is not changed.  You can verify that by doing `show autovacuum` in `psql`.  It is always best to check the actual setting in the running server, when in doubt